# Trying to transpose in an if then statement

Tags: vba, transpose

Large project, need help with a sub that is called out in another sub

This isnt outputting anything and the sub that calls it is working but not this part

```
`Private Sub Data100()

 Dim b1 As Integer
 Dim sourceRange As Range
 Dim targetRange As Range
 b1 = Range("V8").Value

If b1 = 0.015625 Then
Set sourceRange = Range("U150", "X150")
Set targetRange = Range("U201", "U204")
sourceRange.Copy
targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
End If

End Sub`
```

no error message, just wont output anything. Would like to copy U150-X150 and output in column U201-U204

Comment: You haven't specified the worksheet that your `Range`s are on. Implicitly they are on the `ActiveSheet`. Is that what you want?

Comment: You need to change your Range to be `Range("U150:X150")` or else you need to setup a UNION. Also, don't `pastevalues`.

Comment: You also have an `Integer` that should be a `DOUBLE` if it can be a decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further review, I was incorrect about the syntax range being defined incorrectly. I've never seen using `Range("U150","X150")` but it appears to be the same result as `Range("U150:X150")`. You get an uptick for this discovery!

Soo... the only thing wrong that I can see with your code that your `if-statement` is returning `False` because you have `B1` defined as an `Integer` and your if statement is checking for being **equal to** a decimal [which it will never be](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/integer-data-type). If you redefine `B1` as `Double`, I think your code will work as shown below. I ran this slightly modified code of yours successfully.

Also, avoid using `Integer` in general. Just use `Long`. See [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/51689021#51689021) on some discoveries from the SO community. The memory savings isn't worth it.

```
Private Sub Data100_Modified()

 Dim b1 As Double, sourceRange As Range, targetRange As Range

With ActiveSheet

b1 = .Range("V8").Value


If b1 = 0.015625 Then
Set sourceRange = .Range("A1","A3")
Set targetRange = .Range("B2","d2")

sourceRange.Copy
targetRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Even though the original wasn't, some indentation would be a nice touch.